# Memory Leakage with std::queue

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have multithreaded application that one consumer writes to the queue and the producer reads from it.Here is my code;

```
//my_class.h

class My_class{

   My_class();

   double time;

   struct my_struct my_struct;

   unsigned char my_buffer[1000];

   My_class& operator=(const My_class &copy);

};


 //my_class.cpp

   My_class::My_class(){

      my_struct.mem1=30;

      my_struct.mem2=100;

      //other struct assignments.

      time=0.0;

      memset(buffer,0xEF,sizeof(buffer));

   }

   My_class& My_class::operator=(const My_class& copy){

       if(this!=&copy){

           my_struct.mem1=copy.my_struct.mem1;

           my_struct.mem2=copy.my_struct.mem2;

           memcpy_s((void*)buffer,copysize,(void*)copy.buffer,copy.buffer.copysize)

           time=copy.time;
       }
      return *this;
   }
```

In main have a queue;

```
 std::queue<My_class> my_queue;

 My_class my_class_variable;//Filled somewhere in thread1

  //thread1.cpp


   My_mutex.lock();

      my_queue.push_back(my_class_variable);

   My_mutex.unlock();

  //thread2.cpp


   My_mutex.lock();

      my_queue.pop();

   My_mutex.unlock();
```

When I profile the code I see lots of memory leaks when I do push and pop to the queue.what can be the problem?

Comment: What is `copy.buffer.copysize`? Better post some real code. Also, it doesn't look like you need to provide an assignment operator.

Comment: @juanchopanza it is the same size actually.it is a copy assignment

Comment: What are you using to determine that there are memory leaks? I don't see anything in the code you posted that could possibly result in a memory leak (assuming the `buffer` used in `memset` is actually `my_buffer`.

Comment: @Lilshieste There's nothing in the code posted that could possibly compile :-)

Answer (score -2):

Add a coping constructor.

```
My_class(const My_class &copy)
{
(*this) = copy;
}
```

Comment: Isn't this asking for trouble? It doesn't really create a new object, y'know.

Comment: my_queue.push_back(my_class_variable);  calls copying constructor.

Comment: Your class has an error. You could check this, put break point into it.